# Function Issue - Truth Value is Ambiguous

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

I'm building a function to calculate the distance between start latitude and longitude, vs stop latitude and longitude. I made a single variable and it worked fine, but when I make a function, I get the message;

> 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0'

Below is my function. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (notes for this, columns being used have no nulls and are all float64. Orders is the dataframe being used.).

```
def distance_calc (row):
    start = (orders['start_lat'], orders['start_lon'])
    stop = (orders['stop_lat'], orders['stop_lon'])

    return great_circle(start,stop).meters

orders['distance'] = orders.apply(lambda orders: distance_calc (orders), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need select `Series` called `row` instead `orders`:

```
def distance_calc (row):
    start = (row['start_lat'], row['start_lon'])
    stop = (row['stop_lat'], row['stop_lon'])

    return great_circle(start,stop).meters

#lambda is not necessary
orders['distance'] = orders.apply(distance_calc, axis=1)
```